# Speed up pairwise compare of two strings

Tags: python, performance

I have a list with two strings (containing a sequence and some spaces). I need to go pairwise over the two strings and compare each character and count the places where both are not equal to a space

I have this, but it is too slow for my needs. Is there a way to speed this up?

```
from itertools import izip

def overlap(sequence_pair):
    return sum(nucleotide1 != ' ' and nucleotide2 != ' ' for nucleotide1, nucleotide2 in izip(*sequence_pair))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sequence_pair = ['   AT GT ',
                     ' GTAGCG  ']
    print overlap(sequence_pair)
```

Comment: I doubt it, frankly; not at the Python level, at any rate.

Comment: It's amazing how popular Python appears to be among biologists. Every second Python question I see deals with sample strings consisting mostly of 'AGCT' :-}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be hard to optimize your code in Pure Python, but if you use NumPy arrays from the start instead of Python lists/strings then you can get a significant speedup:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> sequence_pair = ['   AT GT '*10000, ' GTAGCG  '*10000]
>>> sequence_pair_arr = np.array([list('   AT GT '*10000), list(' GTAGCG  '*10000)])
>>> %timeit overlap(sequence_pair)
100 loops, best of 3: 14 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.all(sequence_pair_arr != ' ', axis=0).sum()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Depending on how the data is read, the conversion to np.array could take a considerable time as well. Can you add another %timeit which take that into account as well?

Comment: @HannesOvrén Of course data conversion is going to take some time, and they should start with NumPy's data-structures from the start if they want an efficient solution.

Comment: This gave me about four times an increase in speed. Thanks!

Comment: this prints 30000, but should in not print 20000 (2 overlaps * 10000)?

Comment: @kezzos: there are three overlaps (A-A, T-G and G-G).